# Grub Rescue when trying to boot into my main drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I installed the latest Ubuntu onto an External Hard Drive just about 30 minutes ago. The drive was sdc with a boot portion and a swap as well. Upon restarting my computer, I came face to face with a Grub Rescue screen. Before freaking out, I restarted my computer and attempted to boot straight into my main drive instead (sda).
Grub Rescue.

I never touched the drive in the partition menu when installing, so I don't know what is causing this to happen.

I restarted again and attempted to boot into Ubuntu through my External HD I had just installed it on, and instead of the Grub Rescue, I was met with a black screen. 
So I had to resort to using my USB with the Linux installer on it, and clicking "Try Linux" to come onto the forums and ask for help.
I can see my main drive and the contents of it through the File viewer, but I cannot boot into it thanks to Grub.

I am panicking because this is the first time I have ever had any issues with this, and not to mention if my Main Drive somehow became un-bootable, I'd have just lost 500GB of data (most of which is important), and my OS.
I have looked at a few threads with the same issue, but their versions of Ubuntu were outdated so the solutions didn't work.

Is there any way I could boot into my main drive?

Answer (score 0):

Burn Ubuntu to USB flash, boot using it.

then use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to repair the boot

That's worked for me in a similar situation.